# cocos2d js - Touch on overlay sprites that move up together

Tags: sprite, overlay, cocos2d-js

I used latest version cocos2d-js to create my game. On the game screen, I added multiple sprites overlay in a row, like this
[Overlay sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0As6m.png)

I added an event listener to move up a sprite on y-axis when it was clicked. However, when I clicked on the point that any two sprites contain, the two sprites moved up together.

This is my event listener code

```
    var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
    event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
    swallowTouches: true,
    onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {     
        var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
        var location = target.convertToNodeSpace(touch.getLocation());
        var targetSize = target.getContentSize();
        var targetRectangle = cc.rect(0, 0, targetSize.width, targetSize.height);
         if (cc.rectContainsPoint(targetRectangle, location)){
            target.setPositionY(50);
         }      
    }
});
```

How can I prevent to move them up together and move only one sprite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTouchBegan` must returns boolean value as result, if returns `true` it's means touch was handled and event cycle will be stopped. Try to return `true`, if rect contains point. 
Hope this helps. And sorry for my English.

Comment: It works. I saw the return in the sample code, but I didn't what it was for. I tried to google but there wasn't any explanation. Thanks a lot. :)